# Opening VS 2012 C++ Project in VS 2015 gives Build error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, autocad, objectarx

We have a C++ Project built in VS 2012 (To generate .arx files to work with AutoCad 2014). Now we need to recompile it in VS 2015. we have not installed VS 2012. I opened the project in VS 2015. Properties -> General -> Platform toolset is set to Visual Studio 2015 (v140). Still we are getting "The build tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, please install v140 build tools."

we created a simple C++ Console application and ran it. Works fine no build error there.

Need to recompile the files for building .arx files to work in AutoCad 2018.

Initial Project Load :->
[image]

In the initial project load itself for Nimcad and planact we are getting build tools error. But not for engr.

Build on engr Project getting errors this might be the changes in ObjectARX 2018 I don't know. If you have a solution for this error please let us know:->

[image]

Buid on Nimcad Project :->

[image]

Build on Planact Project :->

[image]

For both Nimcad and planact all we get is build tools error.

Property Pages :

[image]

[image]
Any help please.

Comment: Are you selecting all 'Configuration' and 'Platform' from the VS Project's settings dialog when changing the toolset?
Or it seems you don't have C++ toolset installed with the visual studio. Please add it from the control panel from the VS 2015 installer.

Comment: I was not selecting all 'Configuration' and 'Platform'. Now I did. But still showing the same error. When I tried to modify all the items under Visual C++ is selected.

Comment: Check check if the C++ toolset is installed for the Visual Studio. From the control panel, select VS 2015->change-> and then modify and make sure C++ is selected under "Programming Languages"

Comment: Yes it is selected and all the checkboxes under C++ is also selected

Answer (score 0):

To build AutoCAD 2018 ObjectARX app you'll need **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** configured (by default) with VC14.0. As you are migrating a project, make sure to adjust all libraries (.lib files) to version 22. Did you download the [ObjectARX 2018 SDK](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=785550)?

**Update**

This seems a problem with your Visual Studio installation. If you create a new C++ project, VS should also ask you to install the missing parts.

> In Visual Studio 2015 (...) the C++ compiler, libraries, and project templates have been moved into an optional feature. (...) To install the various components needed for desktop and mobile development in C++, you must choose “Custom” and manually select those items ([Visual C++ Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/))

You may need to re-run VS setup and select the C++ related parts (as already mentioned on the question comments).

Finally, check your VisualStudioVersion using the VS2015 Command Prompt:

[image]

Comment: Yes I have downloaded ObjectARX 2018 SDK. In our C++ Project the location of SDK is hardcoded to C:\ObjectARX so we have placed all the folders of the SDK to this location. As I am new to C++ compilation and stuff can you guide me how to adjust .lib files to version 22.

Comment: Hi please can you guide me what to do because I uninstalled VS 2015 and reinstalled everything. It's VS 2015 update 3 and still I am getting build tools not found error. We have three projects in the solution. On project does not give build tools not found error it gives other error in code. But the other two projects gives this build tools not found error. Please help us out

Comment: I followed a post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539801/building-visual-studio-2015-c-project-v140-by-msbuild-failed-v140-cannot-b . It said something about setting environment variable VisualStudioVersion to 14.0. Where should I check this environment variable. Should I check in Control Panel->Environment Variables ( I checked this environment variable is not present) or in VS->Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging ( I added the environment variables there but still no luck) What am I missing can somebody please help us out here.

Comment: can also edit your question with the errors you are getting? number or a print screen

Comment: Hi Previously maybe due to my activity on stackoverflow I was not able to add images. But now I can. I have updated the question with images. Please look into it and see if you can provide a solution for the problem. Also a request can we have a live chat on webex or something where you can actually see into my system. If it is feasible for you please let me know your availability I will create a meeting request.

Comment: Hi in VS 2015 command prompt we are getting 14.0 itself as version. And we have installed C++ components. Let us check again.